# What multiplers and bonuses can you attain during a round of Dungeon Defenders? 

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I've looked around but can't seem to find a centralized list of all the bonuses and multipliers one can strive for during a round of Dungeon Defenders.

I see that if the crystal doesn't get attacked, no damage taken, etc, but what I'd like to see is a bulleted list of everything I could attempt to attain for maximum XP-age.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Score is determined in several ways:

1. Speed to complete the mission
2. Player and Team bonuses (listed below)
3. Killing Enemies

Wave Bonuses:

- Immortal - Did not die throughout the entire match
- Invincible - Did not take damage for an entire wave after the first
- Knight - Killed 10 enemies in 5 seconds
- Lord - Killed 50 enemies in 5 seconds
- Strategist - Scored the most tower kills
- Banker - Earned the most mana
- Trigger Happy - Most first to ready for Combat Phase
- Handy Man - Performed the most tower repairs
- Janitor - Scored the last kill in the wave
- Chillax - Moved the least distance in the wave
- Flawless Victory - No core damage after the first wave
- Most Valuable Hero - Scored the most player kills
- Teamwork - Completed a mission with 4 active players
- Skin of Your Teeth - Survived a wave after the first with <100 Crystal Health Points on at least Medium difficulty
- First Kill - Scored the first kill in the wave
- Mechanic - Performed the most tower upgrades
- Boss Slayer - Your Hero or Defense landed the killing blow on a boss
- Master Builder - Kept full Defense Units throughout the wave
- Master Strategist - Only used Defenses to harm enemies after the first wave
- Gunslinger - Only used Abilities/Weapons to harm enemies after the first wave
- Most Valuable Player - Scored the most total kills

I have read that the algorithm used to calculate the score is rather complex, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere. I don't know if Trendy has released it.

[Source](http://www.destructoid.com/pro-guide-to-dungeon-defenders-solo-play-general-tips-214259.phtml)

"The information in that guide is pretty decent... just do your best to ignore the eleven-year-old comments at the bottom."

Comment: This could be a separate question, but given that several achievements ask you to make sure you have gotten one of these on all levels, or X number of levels, is there anyway to check if you got an award on any particular level?

Comment: Should probably be another question, but you can view what medals you have gotten, on which levels, and on which difficulty, in your own tavern. Click on your own crystal and select statistics.

Comment: Some of these on the list aren't multipliers but just flat bonuses. There is also a wave time bonus, for completing the wave faster?