# Where does the experience awarded at the end of a wave come from?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

**Preface**: From [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33044/16793) question, we know that experience(XP) is shared among all participants for each enemy killed. You can see your XP meter increasing as enemies are killed, so that's fairly obvious. Once the final enemy in the wave is killed, you get an additional lump sum of XP from somewhere. In [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47414/multipliers-given-during-a-round-of-dd) question, it is hinted at that getting more score multipliers increases the amount of XP that you get, but this can't be factored into the XP from killing since multipliers aren't determined until the end of the round.

**Question**: Considering all of the information above, does the extra bonus XP at the end of a wave correspond directly to your score for that round? Or is it from something else entirely?

For example, I start with 0 XP and complete a wave by killing enemies worth a total of 10 XP. If my score for that wave (after multipliers have been taken into account) is 25, does that mean that I now have 35 XP?

Comment: I'm asking mostly because I'm curious whether getting more multipliers will help me level my characters faster.

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but the score multipliers does affect the extra xp you get for completing a wave - not taking damage during a wave will get you more xp than if you died during it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article on the wiki seems to answer it:

http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Awards

Some awards give you an additional lump sum of xp (Knight, Lord, et al) and others multiply the amount of xp you got during that wave.

So you earned 10 xp killing enemies and took no core damage.  Ignoring any other rewards you'd get the "No Core Damage" end-of-wave award will award you an additional 13 xp (10xp * 1.3) giving you a total of 23xp for the wave.

I'd need to look more closely, but it appears that's how it works.  You certainly seem to get more xp after the wave is over than during the wave in my experience.

Comment: I just created a new character to test xp gain, and currently my score has matched my xp gain - i.e. getting 10xp from killing and the no core damage multiplier 1.3 gets me a total score of 13 and a total of 13xp (as in not an extra 13xp but only an extra 3xp). A lot of the awards are flat bonuses that can be worth more than the points you earn in a wave, especially if you aren't killing in multiplayer (although xp is shared while score is not, which adds to the discrepancy between xp and score).

Comment: Also, say in Wave 2 you earn 20xp from killing, and the no core damage award again (and nothing else, for the sake of this example). Your total score (and also total xp, assuming this was the first map you are playing) would then be 13 (from Wave 1) + (20*1.3) = 39. (If this is not your first map, then your xp is whatever you had at the start of the map, plus your score.) (Again, assuming single player.)